# Strategy.close after x bars

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm quite new to this and I was wondering how it's possible to add a strategy.close function additionally after x bars.

So, I'd like to exit the long/short trades either when there comes a signal in the opposite direction (as I have implemented it currently) or after x bars.

Thanks in advance for any help. Much appreciated.

Right now I have the entry and exit conditions as following:

````
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=buy_1 or buy_2,
 alert_message="{{strategy.order.action}} for {{ticker}} at {{strategy.order.price}}")
strategy.close("Long", when=sell_1 or sell_2, comment="Text for Exit here")
 
// strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry="Long", limit=tpLevel_long, stop=slLevel_long, comment="")

// Entry and exit logic for short

if sell_1 or sell_2
    alert(message="Add Short text here")

strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when=sell_1 or sell_2, 
 alert_message="{{strategy.order.action}} for {{ticker}} at {{strategy.order.price}}")
strategy.close("Short", when=buy_1 or buy_2, comment="Text for Exit here")

// strategy.exit("Exit Short", from_entry="Short", limit=tpLevel_short, stop=slLevel_short, comment="")```
````

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your strategy:

```
barsSinceLastEntry() =>
    strategy.opentrades > 0 ? bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades - 1) : na

// Close the long position after 10 bars. 
if barsSinceLastEntry() >= 10
    strategy.close_all(comment="Close")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index` built-in variable to get the bar index of the entry. Then add a check based on current bar index.

```
entry_idx = strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index
diff = bar_index - entry_idx

if (diff > 10)
    strategy.close("Long")
```